# Is there a way to detect if an app was closed via the back button?

Tags: android, flutter

When you close a flutter app via the back button on Android, there are some problems concerning plugins. The dart/flutter side of the plugin gets restarted, the android part not. This causes trouble, especially with background activities like playing audio.
I think it is a critical issue so I created a GitHub issue: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/31734

I want to do a workaround, so if the app gets closed via the back button, the playback should get stopped.

I tried to detect the back button close action via the `didChangeAppLifecycleState` method. But there I can determine if it is a normal close action or with the back button.

You can try this yourself with the example of the [audioplayers](https://github.com/luanpotter/audioplayers) plugin. I also created there a new [issue](https://github.com/luanpotter/audioplayers/issues/144)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you cannot precisely determine whether an app has been closed via the back button. Instead, you can determine if an app is going to be closed via the back button using the [back_button_interceptor](https://pub.dev/packages/back_button_interceptor#-readme-tab-) as an intermediate:

```dart
bool myInterceptor(bool stopDefaultButtonEvent) {
  String currentRoute = BackButtonInterceptor.getCurrentNavigatorRouteName(context);

  if (currentRoute == '/home') {
    // Back button has been pressed while you're in the home, so the app is going to close
    doYourStuff();
  }

  return false;
}
```

Of course you have to implement routes to make this happen, but that is the most precise approach I could find, since everything that creates an overlay (and so overrides back button action) changes the result of `getCurrentNavigatorRouteName`, including dialogs and even `PopupMenu`s from `AppBar`.

Comment: Well; I can detect if the back button was pressed, but I can't detect if it is the tap that closes the app.

Comment: @Butzlabben Please, take a look at my edit and let me know if it works for you.